# how to access kotlin code from java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, use-case

Hi I have a kotlin use case which I want to call from java code how can I do that. this is what I have tried

this is my use case

```
@PerApp
class OnStandUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val orderRepository: OrderRepository,
    private val serviceOrderTypeProvider: ServiceOrderTypeProvider
) : UseCaseCoroutine<GenericResponse, OnStandUseCase.Params>() {

    override suspend fun run(params: Params) = orderRepository.notifyOnStand(
        serviceOrderTypeProvider.apiPathFor(params.serviceType),
        params.id,
        params.action
    )

    data class Params(val serviceType: String, val id: String, val action: TimestampedAction)
}
```

UseCaseCoroutine

```
abstract class UseCaseCoroutine<out Type, in Params> where Type : Any {

    abstract suspend fun run(params: Params): Type

    operator fun invoke(params: Params, onResult: (type: Type) -> Unit = {}) {
        val job = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { run(params) }
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { onResult(job.await()) }
    }
}
```

This is how I call it from my kotlin class

```
  try {
            onStandUseCase(OnStandUseCase.Params(serviceType, id, action)) {
                callback.invoke(it)
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            onStandResponseErrors()
        }
```

But what is the equivalant to call from java class

this is what I tried

```
 onStandUseCase.run(new OnStandUseCase.Params("abcd", "1", new TimestampedAction("1","2"))){
            
        }
```

I get an error `Expected 2 arguments but found only one`

Not exactly sure what is the right way to call the use case from java code

any suggestions please

thanks
R

Comment: Hello @assylias I did try that but did not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `suspend` functions from Java.  (You technically could, but doing it *correctly* would be extremely difficult, and I strongly recommend you just avoid even trying.)

In your Kotlin code, write a function that is *not* a suspend function that converts it to an appropriate Java idiom -- an RxJava result, or a future.  Call *that* method from Java instead.

Comment: ohh noo.. the uses cases were initially using rxjava moved them to Kotlin, well only other way is to convert the java file to kotlin. which is a pain as well as it an old file with around 2000 lines of code.